# Proving that in Spherical geometry, Interior angles of triangles don't add up to $180^{\circ}$.

Tags: differential-geometry

I've gotten a germ of the proof, which involves using the standard metric on the two sphere $ds^2=d\theta^2 + \sin^2{\theta}d\phi^2$. Thing is, how do I continue from here? How do I use this metric to calculate those interior angles regardless of the lengths of the legs of the triangle?

Comment: Do you need to prove for any arbitrary triangle, or would a counter example of the statement ‘interior angles add up to 180’ suffice?

Comment: Note: perhaps $\mathrm d\phi^2$ is correct?

Comment: Not that the metric induces a dot product on the tangent space which can be used to find the angles of the triangle but looking at the initial tangent vectors of the curves forming said triangle

Comment: Soham, the latter but both would be nice to derive.

Comment: Are you interested in a proof that does not use the formula you gave for the *standard* metric on the 2-sphere? I ask because the comment of @Chris would make a very nice answer, although if that does not interest you it might not be worth it.

Comment: Let me just add that the formula you gave is not actually the best primitive definition of the metric; instead, the metric is more properly defined using the dot product method.

Comment: If all you need is a counterexample, look at the simplest triangles you can think of. Remember that each side is part of a great circle, so it's a matter of choosing the great circles. And it's useful to have guideposts such as the north and south poles.

Comment: @LeeMosher are you proposing a counter example which does not depend on a choice of metric? I would personally be very interested in that, and I selfishly suggest you write up an answer if so

Comment: No, I'm proposing a proof that does not depend on spherical coordinates, and it's the same proof proposed by @Chris.

Comment: @LeeMosher oh yes ok that makes much more sense. I think it would probably be easier to not use spherical coordinates at all tbh, at least from a calculation standpoint